# How to play Rayman Legends without Uplay

Tags: steam, ubisoft-connect, rayman-legends

I bought Rayman Legends on Steam a while ago, but when I launch it via Steam, it automatically launches Uplay (which uses about 6 times as much RAM as Steam, and crashes a lot).

Is there any way to play this game (Steam version) without automatically launching Uplay?

Comment: Welcome to Ubisoft games.  Where DRM > user experience.

Comment: @Frank Ha! I don't care about DRM, but Uplay on top of Steam is unnecessary and is just annoying. I wouldn't even mind launching two DRM clients in order to play it (as it's a great game), but it crashes so damn often that I'm reluctant to play.

Comment: Oh, I totally agree!  I'm just saying, that Ubisoft puts piracy concerns above those of their paying customers.

Comment: Should I remove the Rayman Legends tag, as this question applies really to any Steam game that requires Uplay (like Watch Dogs, Driver SF, Far Cry 3, etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, that is how the game is licensed, there is no *legal* way to bypass it. You can try playing in offline mode and seeing what that does, but it will might still be finicky(depends on the game. Playing AC4 offline meant no fleet stuff).

Comment: Did playing AC4 in offline (in Steam) require Uplay to be open (if it did, did it use less RAM?)?

Comment: Yes the programs were still on, but in offline mode(and not intrusive). It did use less resources being offline, but not that much.

Answer (score 0):

no  you cannot play it without uplay.  I just bought it and cannot even play because it will not let me create an account.